# Explanation of YARN's DRF

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm reading "Hadoop The Definitive Guide" of 4th edition, and came across this explanation for YARN'S DRF (in Chapter 4, Dominant Resource Fairness)

> Imagine a cluster with a total of 100 CPUs and 10 TB of memory. Application A requests containers of (2 CPUs, 300 GB), and application B requests containers of (6 CPUs, 100 GB). A’s request is (2%, 3%) of the cluster, so memory is dominant since its proportion (3%) is larger than CPU’s (2%). B’s request is (6%, 1%), so CPU is dominant. Since B’s container requests are twice as big in the dominant resource (6% versus 3%), it will be allocated half as many containers under fair sharing.

I cannot understand the meaning of `it will be allocated half as many containers under fair sharing`. I guess `it` here is `Application B`, and `Application B` is allocated half of the number of Application A's containers. Is it right? Why is `Application B` allocated smaller containers even when it requires more resources?

Any suggestion and indication to some explanation document would be appreciated so much. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Dominant Resource Calculator is based on concept of Dominant Resource Fairness (DRF).

To understand DRF, you can refer to the paper here: https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~alig/papers/drf.pdf

In this paper, refer to section 4.1, where an example is given.

DRF tries to equalise the dominant shares (Memory requirements of A = CPU requirements of B).

**Explanation**

`Total Resouces Available`: 100 CPUs, 10000 GB Memory

`Requirements of Application A`: 2 CPUs, 300 GB Memory

`Requirements of Application B`: 6 CPUs, 100 GB Memory

`A's dominant resource is Memory` (2% of CPUs vs 3% of Memory)

`B's dominant resource is CPU` (6% of CPUs vs 1% of Memory)

Let's assume that "A" is assigned `x` containers and "B" is assigned `y` containers.

1. Resource requirements of A

   ```
   2x CPUs + 300x GB Memory (2 CPUs and 300 GB Memory for each container)
   ```
2. Resource requirements of B:

   ```
   6y CPUs + 100y GB Memory (6 CPUs and 100 GB Memory for each container)
   ```
3. Total requirement is:

   ```
   2x + 6y <= 100 CPUs

   300x + 100y <= 10000 GB Memory
   ```
4. DRF will try to equalise the dominant needs of A and B.

   ```
   A's dominant need: 300x / 10000 GB (300x out of 10000 GB of total memory)

   B's dominant need: 6y / 100 CPUs (6y out of 100 CPUs)

   DRF will try to equalise: (300x / 10000) = (6y / 100)

   Solving the above equation gives: x = 2y
   ```

If you substitute `x = 2y` and solve the equations in step 3, you will get x=20 and y=10.

It means:

- `Application A is allocated 20 containers: (40 CPUs, 6000 GB of Memory)`
- `Application B is allocated 10 containers: (60 CPUs, 1000 GB of memoty)`

You can see that:

`Total allocated CPU is:` 40 + 60 <= 100 CPUs available

`Total allocated Memory is:` 6000 + 1000 <= 10000 GB of Memory available

So, the above solution explains the meaning of the sentence:

```
Since B’s container requests are twice as big in the dominant resource (6% 
versus 3%), it will be allocated half as many containers under fair sharing.
```

Comment: Great and precise explanation, now I've understood it! I think the key concept that I missed is that each requirement refers to a container. I'll read the PDF file later on. Thank you very much!

Comment: Very nice explanation. Thanks for the link.

Comment: how can we implenent such scenario in code ?? CloudSim ? any other simulators ?? anyway to implent this for reasearch,

Comment: in general, DRF is abstracted in such a way that it can be applied to per instance too. not necessarily to containers in a cluster.

Comment: I think I'm having some trouble with the math after step 4.
I get that substituting `x = 2y` into `2x + 6y <= 100 CPUs` gives you `x = 20` and `y = 10`, But why are we just using the constraint for CPUs? Shouldn't you get the same result with memory?
After substitution, I end up with `350x <= 10000 GB` and `700y <= 10000 GB` which ends up with something like `x = 28.57` `y = 14.29`.
Am I missing something? Are you only supposed to substitute into the CPU constraint?